# How can I integrate Pidgin with the indicator/messaging menu without displaying popups?

Tags: unity, indicator, notification, pidgin, libnotify

Since the usability gods work in mysterious ways, in 13.04 it's no longer possible to whitelist systray icons that I want to see. While the messaging menu is less useful than the flashing Pidgin icon (since I can't configure it to flash), it seems I'll have to make do with it.

So I managed to get Pidgin to integrate with that by enabling the libnotify-plugin in Pidgin. However, that leaves me with another problem: How can I have this work (i.e. trigger the messaging menu icon and integrate with that menu) without it actually showing popups for each of those events? At work, I'm often showing coworkers things on my machine, and it is extremely distracting to have these popups show up all the time, not to mention sometimes a privacy issue. Yet when I turn them off, I get no notification whatsoever.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools/Plugins/libnotify/Configure Plugin, then you can uncheck all the events that trigger notifications. They aren't used for the Messaging Menu portion of the plugin.

Comment: I... well that's odd. I tried that, and I was positive that it didn't work - I was getting messages without them showing up in the indicator/messaging menu. I just tried it again, and it appears to be working now. Bizarre. Maybe it only works for newly opened windows? In any case, thanks!

Comment: There is a bug where it sometimes loses the first message which I haven't been able to track down, that may have been what you experienced.